# Is it possible to give sudo access to only a particular command?

Tags: sudo, services

**Background:**
I have a development machine with LAMP setup. Several developers would access the machine from time to time. Every time they make some change in a configuration file they will need to restart the apache server using `sudo service apache restart` or `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

**The Question:**

What I want now is that every developer who accesses the machine does not have a sudo access to everything. Rather, he/she should only be able to run the `service` command using sudo and nothing else. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes.

Make a new group, web (call it what you wish)

```
sudo addgroup web
```

Add your developer(s) to the web group (use their login name).

```
sudo adduser your_developer_user web
```

Then run `sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/somefile` (use a meaningful name instead of `somefile`).

Add in a line (use the full path of the command):

```
%web ALL=(ALL) /usr/bin/service apache2 *
```

The developers can then run

```
sudo service apache
```

using their login password.

**Do NOT add your admin user to the web group.**

See [man sudoers](http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/sudoers.man.html) for additional information

Comment: @Ankit: that way the users of `web` group can start/stop any service, and this is not what you want, I think. The solution should be to put the exact command (also with parameters) in `/etc/sudoers`.

Comment: @enzotib can i do that to i mean so the new command would be `/usr/bin/service apache2` is it?

Comment: @Ankit: `/usr/bin/service apache2 *`

Comment: This should also probably be `/usr/sbin/service`