# Create a Shell with Limited access of commands

Tags: command-line

I have to give ssh access to a user, but i want them to execute only limited command set like ifconfig, ip link,restart apache etc.  but not adduser etc.
Please someone point me in the right direction

Comment: Look for `sudoers` (`man sudoers`, or search for tutorials , e.g. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-edit-the-sudoers-file-on-ubuntu-and-centos or https://www.garron.me/en/linux/visudo-command-sudoers-file-sudo-default-editor.html).

Answer (score 0):

You don't create a restricted shell to do this. These commands need root access, so start by giving them access to a normal user, without root access. Then, use `sudo` to grant them access to specific commands. [Is it possible to give sudo access to only a particular command?](https://askubuntu.com/q/90726/158442)